# Outlook VBA to Save Multiple Attachments as Different Names

Tags: vba, outlook, save, attachment

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "P:\ME\TEST\"
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd")
 For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If InStr(objAtt.FileName, "ASDFA ADSF.pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & " ASDF ASDF.pdf"
        ElseIf InStr(objAtt.FileName, "GASD.pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & " ASDF ADSF ADD.pdf"
        ElseIf InStr(objAtt.FileName, "ASDF AD.pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & " ASDF ASDF.pdf"
        ElseIf InStr(objAtt.FileName, "ASDF AS.pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & " asd asdf.pdf"
        Else
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "Caught"
  End If
  Set objAtt = Nothing
 Next
End Sub
```

I used random letters just for privacy. I'm trying to get outlook to autosave email attachments as specific names with date in front using rules and VBA. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Are you getting an error or is it not displaying properly?

Comment: Nothing happens. Nothing is saved at all. The rule is running and marking the message as read.If it helps, the rule is specific to my name so I'm just forwarding emails to myself and then letting it run to see if it saves the attachments. It runs the script which is under Project 1 in VBA. The script is in Module 2 (deleted module 1 so I think that's why it's 2).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you don't have permission to write to `P:\ME\TEST\` or you aren't getting inside your `If` statements to save.

You want to set your `If` lines to be a `> 0`:

```
If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "BBB AAA.pdf") > 0 Then
```

If any character is in the first position other than that name, then it will not go inside the `If`. Of course, that may also be the behavior you want.

You can test if it is not hitting inside the `If` statments by adding:

```
Else
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "not caught.pdf"
End If
```

If you don't get a save after adding the `Else` code, try saving to your local documents folder. Then, if you still don't get any saves, the `MailItem` doesn't have any attachments.

**EDIT:**
Should look like this:

[image: VBA Editor]

Comment: I have permission and I tried > 0 and put the test to see if it was not hitting and nothing saved still. Any suggestions? I don't know any more ways to get it to hit. It is a client only rule and I'm trying to save to server if that may help.

Comment: Have you set a break point in your `For Each` loop to see if it goes in your `For Each`?

Comment: How would I do that? I'm literally brand new to VBA so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Gray column just to the left of your code, left-click in that column next to a line of code, preferably the first `If` line of code, and a red dot should appear. Then, run your application and if there are any attachments the code should "pause" on your break point. It will be red and highlighted in yellow when it stops. You then want to look at your Locals Window by going to View > Locals Window, expand `itm` once and you should see `Attachments` in there. Let me know if you get that far.

Comment: Nothing pops up on locals when I get an email. The rule runs and marks the message as read but it must not be running the script. Not sure what's going on here. I put the break point in the first if statement.

Comment: Set the breakpoint on the `For Each` line now to see if your code pauses.

Comment: So I got the break point at for each. Looks like everything runs as it should. It picks up that there is 1 attachment etc.

Comment: So now it's saving and catching at the last else statement. So it's saving as "caught" in a shared folder. I don't know why the other else statements aren't picking up the attachment name.

Comment: So the name I'm using for objatt.displayname contains only part of the name of the attachment. Does it need to be exact? I just want it to pickup part of the name since the date is different each day I get the email sent to me.

Comment: So it's like this  If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Backwater Nine.pdf") Then         and the attachment will come in as "Backwater Nine 2016.04.12.pdf" I just want it to pick up part of the name is in there since the date will always change. Also only want it to save the pdf's

Comment: You might try `objatt.FileName` instead. `InStr(objAtt.FileName, "Backwater Nine.pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0` sounds like it should fix it for you. `vbTextCompare` just says non-case sensitive, if you want case-sensitivity then use `vbBinaryCompare`.

Comment: Getting a run-time error 13 type mismatch. Not sure why.

Comment: Which line of your code? Please update what you have so far in your question.

Comment: Looks like the first If statement.

Comment: `InStr(1, objAtt.FileName, "Backwater Nine.pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0` try that. The `1` is for the start position. Sry for the delay, lunch time

Comment: Nothing is catching still. So strange. The last else statement is still what goes through.

Comment: If it hits the `Else`, then the none of your `If` conditions are being met and the `objAtt.FileName` does not match `"Backwater Nine.pdf"` or whatever you are looking to match.

Comment: It matches word for word until the date. So the file name is Backwater Nine 2016.04.02.pdf and the statement goes: If InStr(1, objAtt.FileName, "Backwater Nine.pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

Comment: Then you would need to change to: `InStr(1, objAtt.FileName, "Backwater Nine", vbTextCompare) > 0` if `objAtt.FileName = "Backwater Nine 2016.04.02.pdf"`

Comment: So if I change it to InStr(1, objAtt.FileName, "Backwater Nine 2016.04.02", vbTextCompare) > 0 it works. But I will be getting files with different dates every time. I just want it t look for a few key words. By the way... I really, really appreciate your help! You're awesome for doing this.

Comment: Actually... it works when I takeout .pdf from the name. But I only want PDF files to be saved... any way for this?

Comment: Are you sure the file type of the attachment you are testing is of type `pdf`? When you are debugging, you should be able to hover your mouse over `objAtt.FileName` and it should preview the value for you. You can also copy the value of `objAtt.FileName` from your locals window by expanding `objAtt` until you see `FileName`, then right click and copy. Paste it into your `InStr` where your double quotes are and trim out all the unnecessary stuff that was copied as well.